# Inf2Cat DriverVer set to a date in the future

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, compilation

Am trying to compile microsoft XPS driver sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/XPSDrvSmpl)
but it keeps producing the below error

```
22.9.7: DriverVer set to a date in the future (postdated DriverVer not allowed) in package\xdsmpl.inf.
```

**xdsmpl.inf**

```
DriverVer=08/01/2012,1.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved when I just removed the date and only kept the version, version was then generated using current date

Answer (score 4):

When building your driver, change your driver package project settings so that `Inf2Cat` sets `/uselocaltime`. To do so, use `Configuration Properties->Inf2Cat->General->Use Local Time`.

Comment: right-click on the project in windows explorer and you'll see this property> Inf2Cat. If your solution has multiple projects then click on all of them and set this up